# Extending Grails mocking for unit tests (createCriteria, withNewSession, etc...)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

As part of a Grails project, I'm currently extending my test suite to stuff that need a complete environment to run, like for instance custom HQL and criteria queries, session related issues, etc. I'm using integration tests.

We already have a fairly large number of unit tests (> 500), where we used to mock methods that don't have a Grails mocked counterpart by default (like `withCriteria`, `withNewSession`, etc.) using helper functions like this one:

```
static mockCriteria(Class clazz, returnValue)
{
  def myCriteria = new Expando()
  myCriteria.list = {Closure cls -> returnValue}
  myCriteria.get = {Closure cls -> returnValue}
  clazz.metaClass.static.createCriteria = { -> myCriteria }
}
```

Code could then be tested like this:

```
mockCriteria(MyClass, [result])
assert myClass.createCriteria.list({ ... }) == [result]
```

Until now I always managed to meet my needs using this approach.

Now I want to add integration tests that actually check how methods that *use* criterias and HQL queries behave, in order to facilitate refactoring these queries. I'm stuck by the fact that `createCriteria` is replaced in my tests and don't recover their initial code after the unit tests phase, preventing me from testing them in the integration phase.

How do you address the problem of mocking criteria (or HQL queries, etc.), while allowing to get the original behavior back in integration tests?

*EDIT: Unfortunately, upgrading to Grails 2 is not an option.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather mock not criterias, but domain methods that use them.

Plus, Grails 2.0 promise to have criteria support in unit tests - not HQL, though.

Comment: Thank you Victor. Mocking methods that use custom queries is a good idea. It supposes each query is wrapped in a small instance method (it's good practice, but not the case everywhere here. It's a refactoring I'll suggest). Anyway, it would suppose updating the tests. I hoped for a solution only involving changes to `mockCriteria` or reinitializing the static methods, but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    registerMetaClass MyClass
}
```

Under the Hood

```
def a = [1, 2, 3]
def oldMetaClass = ArrayList.metaClass
ArrayList.metaClass.find = { Closure cls -> 5 }
assert 5 == a.find{ it == 1}

ArrayList.metaClass = oldMetaClass  
assert 1 == a.find{ it == 1 }
```

​

And for mockCriteria take a look

https://github.com/fabiooshiro/plastic-criteria

(works with 1.3.7)